# SELECT from table but remove spaces from value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select from a table using PHP/MySQL.

I want to run:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from customer where phone = :phone ");
$stmt->execute(array(':phone' => $res));
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

in the customer table, phone equals `00000 00 00 00`

but the `$res` equals `00000000000`

how can i make sure they match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use replace... to replace spaces.

```
where replace(phone, ' ', '') = :phone
```

Comment: If the table is huge, this would mean a FULL TABLE SCAN!

Answer (score 0):

**One time operation**: Remove spaces, hyphens and other special chars (let's call it sanitizing here on) from the column `phone`.
**While querying**: Sanitize your `$res` variable.
(that way, the index on `phone` column, if any, is used)

In case you need to retain the original formatting of the phone number, store phone number in two columns: `phone_user_input` (as input by user), `phone` (sanitized)

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using `str_replace`.

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from customer where phone = :phone ");
$stmt->execute(array(':phone' => str_replace(" ","",$res)));
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use trim() or explode for it.

```
explode(" ","00000 00 00 00");
```